# Jest to test HTML String

Tags: javascript, html, unit-testing, jestjs

How do I test a HTML string using Jest?

Right now, I am doing it using regular string comparison like below. When I run this test case, it works fine.

```
it('should compile partial as per the context', () => {
  const receivedOutput = someFunctionReturningHTMLString();
  //*PS: someFunctionReturningHTMLString() is function which returns a html string;*
  //In above call, lets assume it returns `<a href="/" class="some_class1 some_class2" >`

  const expectedResult = `<a href="/" class="some_class1 some_class2" >`;
  expect(receivedOutput .trim()).toEqual(expectedResult.trim())
});
```

However, I don't find this approach of testing pure string values as a good approach.

Can somebody help me with a better way where I can actually test the content of the HTML string? Like testing whether the  tag in the string has a particular class? Something like what we can achieve with Enzyme for React components.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Assuming we're talking about testing with jest and vanilla JS.*

If you want to test that you're returning valid HTML from `someFunctionReturningHTMLString` (which I think it's what matters) another approach would be to create a DOM Element and insert the content returned in the node with `innerHTML`, then you'd be able to test it as normal HTML and make sure it's valid:

```
it('should compile partial as per the context', () => {
  const receivedOutput = someFunctionReturningHTMLString();

  // convert output to actual HTML
  const newNode = document.createElement('div');
  newNode.innerHTML = receivedOutput;

  // Assuming your output is `<a href="/" class="some_class1 some_class2" >`
  const link = newNode.querySelector('a');

  // Test the attributes that matter to you as normal HTML
  expect(link.getAttribute('class')).toBe('some_class1 some_class2')
  expect(link.getAttribute('href')).toBe('/')
});
```

Then it'd be pretty straightforward testing nested elements, text nodes and so on, hope it helps.

Jest's documentation have some examples of [how to work with DOM Manipulation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-jquery) they use jQuery to demonstrate but the applied principle is what matters.

Comment: Enmanuel, I almost did the same thing. I know this is an old post, but thank you for sharing and explaining the thoughts.